# Where are the community wikis?

Tags: support

In the ubuntu Q/A and some of the other stackexchange Q/As', I keep running into references to community wikis. So, where are these wikis? I've looked all around and see no links to wikis.

I'm new to the site, so maybe I'm just missing something.

wdy

Comment: @virtualxtc not a dupe, this ask "what are they" the other is "how I find them".

Comment: @Braiam where in this question does this question as "what"  I only see "where"?  It is most certainly a duplicate of http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/160/finding-community-wikis

Comment: Related (but *not* a duplicate): [Is the “community help wiki” the same as “community wiki” on Ask Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5976/is-the-community-help-wiki-the-same-as-community-wiki-on-ask-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a definition of "Community Wiki" available on the [Stack Overflow meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). As far as I know the information there applies to all other sites built on the Stack Exchange engine.

As I understand it a community wiki question is owned by the whole community instead of an individual user. As a result a lower bar is set for the reputation score needed to do certain things (like edits), and up/down votes do not have the affect reputation scores they would on a normal question.

**Update:** As [noted here by Erigami](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/154/where-are-the-community-wikis/167#167) and [this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/160/finding-community-wikis/166#166) on the Finding community wikis question, a list of community wiki questions can be obtained by using the search term "wiki:1". Here's a link to the results of that search on the parent site:

https://askubuntu.com/search?q=wiki:1

<strike>I am not aware of any method to get a definitive list of questions that have been set to community wiki.</strike>

Comment: I think that it would be cool to have a tag or other such device to identify community wikis.

From the Community Wiki definition on Stack Overflow meta:
"Community Wiki posts help enhance the wiki aspect of the site."

So with that in mind it seems like a good idea to make community wikis more visible.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Finding community wikis](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/160/finding-community-wikis/166#166) question. Apparently you can add `wiki:1` to limit your search to wikis.

Answer (score 0):

community wikis are questions which say community wiki underneath the author of the question.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1598/what-was-your-most-satisfying-hack-using-ubuntu is an example for this.

Comment: So is there a directory somewhere of all questions considered to be community wikis?