# Finding community wikis

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Why isn't there a listing of community wikis?

It seems to me that being able to easily find community wikis would be a great resource [based on the description of community wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

I would assume that there is already a database table or xml file with everything listed as a community wiki. Perhaps there could be a community wiki tag that would yield a listing of community wikis?

Answer (score 4):

Use one of our advanced, super ninja search options:

> wiki:1

Want better search results? [**See our search tips!**](https://meta.askubuntu.com/search)