# The "seemingly went away on its own" close reason is being abused. Again

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

### When should this be used?

> When a **problem goes away** and nobody knows enough about why that an answer would likely help anybody else, voting to close as off-topic with the "a problem that can't be reproduced" sub-reason is appropriate.
>
> Often, when the OP solves their own problem, people vote to close as "a problem that can't be reproduced." **That's wrong**. When the solution might help others with the same problem, the question should be answered.

This is actually totally off: [firefox can't the server at start.unbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641671/firefox-cant-the-server-at-start-unbuntu-com)

[image]

It was asked 18 hours ago. He replied 7 hours ago. He has not said that he can now access `start.ubuntu.com`. I can't see anything there suggesting that his issue has been resolved.

This is another example:

[Can I change or replace Unity Launcher Dash behaviour?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629567/can-i-change-or-replace-unity-launcher-dash-behavior)

Okay, so it was asked a while ago. But how has it been resolved? Has anyone asked the OP if they have solved the issue?

Reminder. The only time you should use this reason is when a problem goes away, *and* the solution is not known.

[And why "again" in the title?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11908/lots-of-closed-as-off-topic-because-it-seemingly-went-away-close-votes)

Comment: What about when the question is worded in such a way that the solution was not the question asked? Such as this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/802710/distribution-upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04-hangs In this case I voted to close my own question as it indicated that the known solution wasn't what I was looking for, there were no answers and the problem is now gone.

Answer (score 3):

For the second example, OP had this to say in the comments:

> Following @xangua's advice decided to switch to xfce, configured it to my needs and everything works fine now, so I voted to close it as it doesn't bother me anymore. Though maybe somebody in the future will be interested in the same so decided not to delete it.